# iOS SDK AVPlayer - how to detect if audio stream is seekable?

Tags: ios, audio, audio-streaming, avplayer

I'm using the AVPlayer to play different audio files. Some of them are static remote mp3s and some are live streams. Is there any way to tell if an audio stream is seekable or not?

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple iOS developer library you can wait until the status of the AVPlayerItem is equal to AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay and then query the duration property. If the value returned is equal to kCMTimeIndefinite then this is likely a live stream playing. If so then you'll know that the stream is not seekable.

[iOS Developer Library - AVPlayer class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check if `seekableTimeRanges` is not empty for you `currentItem`. Something like this should work:

```
let seekSupported = !(player.currentItem?.seekableTimeRanges.isEmpty ?? true)
```